Books that can teach me how to build my own electromagnetic apparatus at home
I am a studying physics at university right now and I wanted to build some projects during the winter and summer break. Projects that specifically use electromagnetic concepts like induction and magnetization and polarization. I do not want anything crazy, I just want to build some small systems to try and see electromagnetic phenomenon in real life. I am already planning to build a van de graaff generator as a first step. If there are any other books that can guide me through the process of building other projects (like small antennas or how to create a spherical capacitor) that would be appreciated.

Tabletop Synchrotron

The magazine Scientific American ran a column called "The Amateur Scientist" for many years, up until about 2001.  Not all of the projects described were about physics, but many of them were.  Many of them would be suitable for a dedicated undergraduate who wanted to learn more about building experimental apparatus.
As far as I can tell, the "Amateur Scientist" columns were only collected in print once, in 1960;  and obviously a lot has changed since then, both in what scientific projects would be of interest, and what materials are readily available to the consumer.  A CD-ROM containing the "complete columnns" was released in 2006, and can still be found via online resellers; if you can get it running, it would be a valuable resource.  Alternately, your local library might have access to back issues of Scientific American, either electronically or old paper copies.
